# Comparar valores de array en PHP

Tags: php

Necesito comparar valores de un `array` en PHP, El `array` contendrá datos de tipo entero. Necesito evaluar que el indice siguiente sea mayor que el anterior. Suponiendo que tengo el siguiente `array`:

```
<?php

   $datos = [12, 15, 20, 9, 11, 30];

?>
```

Como evalúo, por ejemplo que el indice 0 es menor que el indice 1?

Se que lo puedo hacer

```
if($datos[0] < $datos[1]){

        echo "Es menor";
}
```

Pero son muchos elementos, me imagino que tendría que ser con un `for`.
Pero como evalúo que en cada indice el valor sea mayor al anterior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recorres el array desde el segundo elemento comparando con el valor del anterior.

```
$datos = [12, 15, 20, 9, 11, 30];
for ($i=1; $i < count($datos) ; $i++) { 
   if($datos[i]<$datos[$i-1]){
       echo "el elemento ".$i." es mayor" ;
   }
}
```

De este modo evitas el problema con el primer elemento indicado por @CristianS9.

Answer (score 1):

```
$datos = [12, 15, 20, 9, 11, 30];
for ($i=0; $i < count($datos) ; $i++) { 
   if($datos[$i]>$datos[$i+1]){
       echo $datos[$i]." es mayor que ".$datos[$i+1];
   }
}
```

Son las bases de como funciona un for, la variable `$i` es el indice, si añades `+1` a la posición estas accediendo al siguiente, o si haces `$i-1` estas accediendo al anterior

---

Ten en cuenta siempre de no usar `$i+1` con el ultimo ya te dara error y lo mismo con el primero y `$i-1`

Answer (score 1):

```
$datos = [12, 15, 20, 9, 11, 30];
$anterior = null;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($datos); $i++) {
    if ($anterior != null) {
        if ($datos[$i] > $anterior) {
            echo $datos[$i] . ' es mayor que ' . $anterior . '<br />';
        }
    }

    $anterior = $datos[$i]; 
}
```

Podrías usar una variable para guardar el valor de la iteración anterior y así poder compararlo con el valor de la iteración actual. Bastaría con que tras hacer la comparación actualizaras el valor de `$anterior` y listos.